# filter tweets about a specific country in python

Tags: python, json, list

this is a python program that eliminates tweets from outside of a specified country that checks the contact details of each tweet received and whether it belongs at least to a rectangle in a bounding box it takes it and stores it in a text file if it does belongs to the coordinates , otherwise it rejects it. This is the following program:

```
import codecs
import json

f = codecs.open("tweets.json", 'r', 'utf-8')
resultat = open('texte.txt', 'w')
cpt = 0
for line in f:
    if len(line) < 10:
        continue
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    status = json.load(line)
    liste = ['2.704,34.6152,7.9652,36.6056', '2.0228,32.7168,7.4818,34.7812', '- 1.3061,32.7534,2.0216,34.8177',
             '-0.8336,34.0182,2.494,35.6891', '-1.5478,33.597 6,-0.6151,35.2155', '0.1332,35.1851,1.9447,35.9295',
             '1.056,35.6663,2.8675,36.4372', '2.8797,35.9412,3.1202,36.7737',
             '2.8797,35.9412,3.1202,36.7737","-0. 8886,32.3935,7.4928,34.2722', '-0.64,22.87,7.95,32.51',
             '1.21,22.15,9.18,27.94', '1.21,22.15,9.18,27.94', '-8.5,27.43,-0.18,28.57',
             '34.6152,2.704,36.6056, 7.9652']
    if 'coordinates' in status.keys():
        if status['coordinates'] is not None:
            coordinate = '%f,%f' % (status['coordinates']['coordinates'][0], status['coordinates']['coordinates'][1])
            for i in liste:
                x = coordinate.split(',')
                y = i.split(',')
                try:
                    if (float(y[0]) <= float(x[0]) <= float(y[2])) and (float(y[1]) <= float(x[1]) <= float(y[3])):
                        print("we get it")
                        resultat.write(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
resultat.close()
```

i have a problem There are no errors but when I compile the text file is empty, it's supposed to have the json file containing tweets that have the following coordinates in the program
im new to python language i would appreciate some help thank you!

Comment: Do you see the "we get it" prints? If not, you know where the problem is: the code never reaches the part of writing to your file.

Comment: no i don't , thank you for your help! i will try to see where the problem is.

Comment: The best way to go about this is debugging, and see where your program's behaviour is unexpected. You can add print statements after each if statement and see what happens. Or, alternatively, if you're using an IDE: use breakpoints.